# windows virtual machine not starting in virtual box

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

Running windows virtual machine on virtual box. On starting it gets stuck on - 
[image]

Any pointers how do I resolve this ?
Although when I open the fedora virtual machine inside the same virtual box. It runs fine.

Comment: The Windows 10 install apparently went wrong and Windows is trying to repair it. If it will not progress, can you try a new Windows 10 Virtual Machine?

Comment: I did a fresh install. Now it gets stuck here [link](https://ibb.co/Pm6BY6j). When I installed it previously the same issue happened. When I disabled the WSL in my host OS then the installation in the virtual box went fine. That's weird.

Comment: It is possible WSL and Virtual Box do not work in harmony. That is still a work in progress.

Comment: Is VMWARE a good alternative to virtual Box ? Any suggestion for virtualization softwares ?

Comment: I use VMware Workstation. I find it to be an excellent virtualizing app.  I have a Windows Insider laptop and I use Hyper-V and WSL on that. The newest versions of VMware Workstation and Hyper-V / WSL can co-exist.